# Is Hybrid mobile wallet is as just secure than native

Tags: security, light-wallet

For example in the future we will be able to have an implementation that  would allow a light wallet to connect to a remote server. Does a hybrid appp (e.g. Ionic ) is just safer than native? One good example right now  is mymonero.com converted into a mobile app.

I researched about this and only found a researched by IBM on cordova, but the vulnerability is very easy to mitigate and probably is not a problem if the hybrid app is just securely implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run a full node and use the wallet that comes with it, you have complete privacy.  The odds of being robbed go down to practically zero because no one can see what your doing.

When you use any type of a wallet that connects to a remote node, your privacy is gone.  The host of the remote node can see what you are doing.

If you only have a few moneros, no big deal if someone ends up stealing them from the block chain using the keys in your light wallet.  If you have a serious amount of moneros, you would be foolish to use a mobile device and/or a remote node for them to see your keys to the block chain.